# htmldoc ignoring LC_TIME for date format

Tags: perl, locale, htmldoc

I'm running the following Perl code to create a PDF file.

```
{
    local $ENV{LC_TIME} = 'de_DE.utf8';
    system qw(htmldoc --quiet --webpage -t pdf --jpeg --no-link --header .D. --footer .D/ --outfile), "$filename.pdf", $filename;
}
```

It works on my local machine, the date is formatted as 12.02.2013 15:18:19 in both header and footer.

As soon as I run the script on the remote server, I get 02/12/13 15:10:25.

Why is htmldoc ignoring the LC_TIME value?

"locale" already returns LC_TIME="de_DE.utf8" on both my local machine and the server, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your server possibly defines LC_ALL which has precedence over category-specific locale settings.

Comment: Thank you! I just set LC_ALL to de_DE.utf8 in the perl script instead of LC_TIME and now it works.